# Number of solutions of the two equations

Tags: combinatorics, recurrence-relations, integer-partitions

Find the number of integral solutions of the equation:

$a+b+c=m$ with $0\gt a\gt b\gt c$

And the generalized version:

$a_1 + a_2 + \cdots + a_k = m$ with $
0\gt a_1\gt a_2\gt \cdots \gt a_k$

Comment: You are supposed to show us where exactly you got stuck.  Obviously we can't have a website where students just post their HW and others just do it for them.  I'm sure you can see why such a website would not be desirable.

Comment: Search the site for any of the twenty-five billions instances of this question.

Comment: You are asking about how to compute the number of integer partitions of $m$ having $k$ distinct parts.  There are some previous Questions here about how to count these.  I'll update the tags and it should make some related Questions appear in the sidebar.

Answer (score 1):

This is the number of partitions of a given integer into a sum.  Say,
$$m = 6,$$
and we would like to write it as the sum of 3 positive summands.  To do this, write
$$
6 = 1 + 1 + 1 + 1 + 1 + 1.
$$
A sum is formed by choosing 2 of the 5 pluses in the above expression; e.g,
$$
1 + 1 +' 1 + 1 + 1 +' 1 = 2 + 3 + 1.
$$
The number of ways to choose 2 pluses is "5 choose 2".

Comment: Hey thanks for the reply. I am able to do what you just mentioned above. But the condition has more to it. **0>a>b>c**

Comment: $a, b, c$ are negative??